# Update Column by another colum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update one column value by another column value as per in example

```
Name    Category       CategoryID
-------+--------------+----------
apple   fruit     
mango   fruit     
patato  Vagitable
india   Country
Bhutan  Country
```

and i want to update above table as shown in below
logic is:- 
 Order by category in distinct manner and assign id to a category

and then update categoryID for each row.
I need sql query.

```
Name    Category       CategoryID
-------+--------------+----------
apple   fruit          2
mango   fruit          2
patato  Vagitable      3
india   Country        1
Bhutan  Country        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dense_Rank()`

> Returns the rank of rows within the partition of a result set, without
>   any gaps in the ranking. The rank of a row is one plus the number of
>   distinct ranks that come before the row in question.
>
> If two or more rows tie for a rank in the same partition, each tied
>   rows receives the same rank

```
select Name,Category, dense_rank() over(order by category) As CategoryId
From yourtable
```

To Update the table

```
UPDATE A
SET    CategoryId = B.CategoryId
FROM   Yourtable A
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Category,
                          Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY category) AS CategoryId
                   FROM   Yourtable) AS B
               ON A.Category = B.Category
```

Comment: ya first you write query for select but i modify it for update and it seems similar query as my query. thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.CategoryId = D.Id
FROM YourTable AS T
INNER JOIN (SELECT Category, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Category) AS Id
            FROM YourTable) AS D
    ON T.Category = D.Category
```

Comment: i apply Dense_Rank() on your query on replacement of ROW_NUMBER() and i got a result thank you for your answer